# JQuery text change after animations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to animate a div box for several times when a button is pressed. It shall go right, and again right, then it comes a bit down and the text inside should change, and then it shall go left, and again left to its original place. There are two problems that I need help with:

1. The text change doesn't occur when it should! It changes immediately after I press the button! What should I do to run the text change just AFTER the third animation?
2. I get the value of an input number box, and want to apply it as the
   speed argument. But when I put `number` instead of `speed`, it does
   not work. I have to set it manually like 2000. What is wrong here?

**JavaSript Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  var d=$("#t");
  var number=$("#number1").val();
  var speed=2000;

  if(state==true){
        d.animate({left:'+=230px'}, speed);
        d.animate({left:'+=230px'}, speed);
        d.animate({top:'+=20px', backgroundColor: "#f09090", text:'12'}, speed/4);
        $('#span').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).text('a1').fadeIn(500);
        });     
        d.animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed);
        d.animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed);
        d.fadeOut();

        }
  });
});
```

Comment: @Foreever - Animations in jQuery are queued: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/qn893/ So therefore they will not execute simultaneously.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - Ah I didn't read the code in detail. Well simply add `.queue` will solve the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/qn893/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try this: use .when and .then

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/9RuTX/1/

In terms of your #2 problem. I tested it out and it seems to work fine. Have you consoled it out and see if its getting in your var number. Perhaps do a typeof on it and see what it is.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  var d=$("#t");
  var number=$("#number1").val();
  var speed=2000;
  if(state==true){
        $.when(
        d.animate({left:'+=230px'}, speed),
        d.animate({left:'+=230px'}, speed),
        d.animate({top:'+=20px', backgroundColor: "#f09090", text:'12'}, speed/4)
       ).then( function(){
            $('#span').fadeOut(500, function() {
                  $('#span').hide().text('a1').fadeIn(500);
            })
          }
             ).then( function(){
        d.animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed)
        d.animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed)
        d.fadeOut()
        }
       )
  }
  });
});
```

Comment: ummm, don't know why it doesn't work! Now when I press the button, nothing happens, even the animations!

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle. Let me get one for what i just posted for you. Just a minute.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jsfiddle. But I think you mean the link: http://jsfiddle.net/9RuTX/

Comment: ok - added jsfiddle. tested. seems to work well. See my original post for fiddle.

Comment: Great! This one seems better simpler!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because jQuery enqueue's animations per-element, and the span is a different element. You should put the text changing code in a callback function for when the previous animation completes. Here's an example.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  var d=$("#t");
  var number=$("#number1").val();
  var speed=2000;

  if(state==true){
        d.animate({left:'+=230px'}, speed);
        d.animate({left:'+=230px'}, speed);
        d.animate({top:'+=20px', backgroundColor: "#f09090", text:'12'}, speed/4, "swing", function(){
            $('#span').fadeOut(500, function() {
                $(this).text('a1').fadeIn(500);
            });
        });
        d.animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed);
        d.animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed);
        d.fadeOut();

        }
  });
});
</script>
```

If needed, you can also delay you following animation so that it will not run simultaneously with the text changing code like this.

```
d.delay(500).animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed);
```

Here is a working example based on you jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/LSegC/

Comment: ummm, don't know why it doesn't work! Now when I press the button, nothing happens, even the animations!

Comment: @TinaJasmin: Sorry, there was an error in my code. I have fixed it.

Comment: @TinaJasmin: Strange, can you make a jsFiddle that shows your example? Assuming state is declared somewhere within your code, this code should work, athe only difference is that it moves the text-changing code into the animation callback handler.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jsfiddle. But I think you mean the link: http://jsfiddle.net/9RuTX/

Comment: @TinaJasmin: Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/LSegC/ (I don't know what the state variable is meant to represent, so I commented it out).

Comment: Yes, state is just for my test...does nothing! :D

Comment: Alexander, thank you a lot. I have another question how to make two divs, and then three divs to run like this...I will ask it as another question now...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    d.animate({left:'+=230px'}, speed)
     .animate({left:'+=230px'}, speed)
     .animate({top:'+=20px', backgroundColor: "#f09090", text:'12'}, speed/4)
     .queue(function(){
         var q = $(this);
         $('#span').fadeOut(500, function() {
             $(this).text('a1').fadeIn(500, function(){ q.dequeue() });
         });
     })
     .animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed)
     .animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed)
     .fadeOut();
```

Just add it to the animation queue and it will get executed after the previous animations are done.

Related demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/qn893/1/